# Как делать JOIN таблицы с самой собой?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Исходная таблица имеет следующий вид:

```
CREATE TABLE public.psi_humsensor (
  id           serial NOT NULL,
  sensorblock  integer NOT NULL,
  psi_act      integer NOT NULL,
  chamber_hum  real,
  sensor_hum   real,
  /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT psi_humsensor_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
  /* Foreign keys */
  CONSTRAINT foreign_key01
    FOREIGN KEY (psi_act)
    REFERENCES public.psi_humsensor_acts(id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
  CONSTRAINT foreign_key02
    FOREIGN KEY (sensorblock)
    REFERENCES public.sensorblock(id)
) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  );
```

Таблица заполнена такими данными:

[image: Данные в таблице]

Пытаюсь из этой таблицы сформировать отчёт. Для этого нужно составить запрос, который вернул бы влажность датчика в камере при 25%, влажность тестируемого датчика при 25%, влажность датчика в камере при 95%, влажность тестируемого датчика при 95%. Написал такой запрос:

```
SELECT
      sb.serial_number
     ,t.label_number 
     ,round(CAST(psi1.chamber_hum as numeric), 2) AS ch25
     ,round(CAST(psi1.sensor_hum as numeric), 2) AS sh25
     ,abs(round(CAST((psi1.chamber_hum - psi1.sensor_hum) as numeric), 2)) as delta25
     ,round(CAST(psi2.chamber_hum as numeric), 2) AS ch95
     ,round(CAST(psi2.sensor_hum as numeric), 2) AS sh95
     ,abs(round(CAST((psi2.chamber_hum - psi2.sensor_hum) as numeric), 2)) as delta95
FROM psi_humsensor psi1
     JOIN psi_humsensor psi2 ON (psi1.psi_act = psi2.psi_act AND psi1.sensorblock = psi2.sensorblock)
     JOIN sensorblock sb ON (sb.id = psi1.sensorblock)
     JOIN termistors t ON (t.id = sb.termistor)
WHERE 
      psi1.id <> psi2.id 
  AND psi1.psi_act = 3
```

При выполнении этого запроса получаются дублирующие записи, например:

1 | 1 | 25.2 | 25.3 | 0.1 | 95.3 | 95.5 | 0.2

2 | 2 | 95.3 | 95.5 | 0.2 | 25.2 | 25.3 | 0.1

Если добавить в запрос `SELECT DISTINCT(psi1.chamber_hum + psi2.chamber_hum)`, то дублирование исчезает, но иногда путаются записи: в левой части таблицы оказываются данные при 95%, в правой - при 25%. Как правильно составить такой запрос?

Comment: Я вообще не вижу, где у Вас выполняется отбор по заданным параметрам (25% и 95%). Единственный отбор в запросе - это psi1.psi_act = 3. А чтобы не было "обмена местами" - добавьте в условие связывания соотв. отборы (например AND psi1.sensor_hum < 30 AND psi2.sensor_hum > 90).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам вообще не нужен самоджойн.
Вся нужная информация уже есть, нужно просто добавить группировку:

```
SELECT
      sb.serial_number
     ,t.label_number 
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN psi.sensor_hum < 30 THEN
         round(CAST(psi.chamber_hum as numeric), 2)
      END) AS ch25
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN psi.sensor_hum < 30 THEN
         round(CAST(psi.sensor_hum as numeric), 2) 
      END) as sh25
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN psi.sensor_hum < 30 THEN
         abs(round(CAST((psi.chamber_hum - psi.sensor_hum) as numeric), 2))
      END) as delta25
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN psi.sensor_hum > 90 THEN
         round(CAST(psi.chamber_hum as numeric), 2)
      END) AS ch95
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN psi.sensor_hum > 90 THEN
         round(CAST(psi.sensor_hum as numeric), 2) 
      END) as sh95
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN psi.sensor_hum > 90 THEN
         abs(round(CAST((psi.chamber_hum - psi.sensor_hum) as numeric), 2))
      END) as delta95
FROM psi_humsensor psi
     JOIN sensorblock sb ON (sb.id = psi.sensorblock)
     JOIN termistors t ON (t.id = sb.termistor)
WHERE psi.psi_act = 3
GROUP BY sb.serial_number, t.label_number 
/*тут возможно надо добавить группировку по psi.sensorblock*/
```